# Uncaught OAuthException: Access taken expiring too soon

Tags: facebook

Please see the below code:

```
 $fbconfig['appid' ] = "..........";
$fbconfig['api'   ] = "..........";
$fbconfig['secret'] = ".......................";
 try{
    include_once "src/facebook.php";
}
catch(Exception $o){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($o);
    echo '</pre>';
}
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,  
));
$user       = $facebook->getUser();
$uid=$user;
```

The problem is that .....the script works fine when executed once. (The script is being used to upload a picture on Facebook by the user through an ajax call.
However, if the script is called immediately once again, or is called after a few minutes of the authentication, it gives the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in ..... on line 1125
```

Please advice!